# OpenGL Rotate two angles at the same time (neglicting order of glRotate)?

Tags: opengl, rotation

I am trying to rotate an object around a global axis. However, 1st glRotate call is effected by 2nd glRotate (rotation matrix is applied in reverse order). Therefore, even though I want to rotate my object around global x and y axis by angle1 and angle2 respectively, my object behave in such a way that object is rotated by angle2 about the global Y-axis, while object is rotated by angle1 about the local x-axis.

```
glRotate(angle1,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
glRotate(angle2,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
draw(..);
```

How would I rotate about both global axis without one affecting the other?

Comment: You can't. If you apply two rotations then one is relative to the other. If changing the order doesn't get you what you want, then you should rethink what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @JasonD, do I have to generate my own rotation matrix and manually apply it?

Comment: Well you may well be better off doing that anyway, but it won't necessarily solve your problem.